# formatting namenode, node is lost

Tags: hadoop, distributed

I'am trying to set up the pseudo distributed mode for Hadoop. all first steps are ok, but when I format the namenode and browse the filesystem (50070), it shows "there are no datanode in the cluster"

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html

should I do other configuration? change directory path?

thanks

Comment: After formatting the NameNode, are you starting the HDFS?

Comment: show me your config files.

Comment: @LMHadoop - please move your comments into the original question and apply some fixed formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it looks like you've formatted your name node twice, but not deleted the underlying data for the data node.

I suggest you clean up as follows:

- Ensure that all hadoop services are stopped (`bin/stop-all.sh`)
- Remove all data in the directories named in `conf/hdfs-site.xml` conf file

  - `dfs.name.dir`
  - `dfs.data.dir`
- Reformat the name node again
- Start HDFS only (`bin/start-dfs.sh`)
- Check the logs for both the name node and data node to ensure that everything started without error

If you're still having problems, post your name node and data node logs back into your original question